# Define intervals in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with several equal values

[1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,9,9,9.9]

I would like a way to get a new array by separating equal values.

For example, the new arrays would have values
[1,1,1,1]
[5,5,5,5]
[1,1,1,1]
[2,2,2,2]
[5,5,5]
[9,9,9,9]

For those new arrays,I must find the index when items changes.

This is what i've tried so far

```
indices = []; // fill with information when items in array change
arreglo = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,9,9,9.9];
for ( u=0; u <= arreglo.length; u++){
            if ( arreglo[u] !=  arreglo[u + 1])
            indices.push(u);
            }
```

The idea is finding the index of the biggest array and then loop in it to create the new ones.

Using a loop i would go from 0 to indices[0], later from indices[0] to indices[1] and so on.

It does not work properly, have problems. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Update: This is not homework, it's for a site for a client. I made a question before [Need ideas: Selecting rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323931/need-ideas-selecting-rows-in-table) but couldnt make it with mysql so i decided using jQuery

{
This is the real code i'm using http://jsfiddle.net/U58jh/

In the jsfiddle example this is working good but not always when using different data from a php generated page.

The script must find the last dates (fecha) with a final percent (Porcentaje final) iquals. 
}

Comment: Forgive me if I sound nasty and suspicious, but is this (1) homework and/or (2) an interview (or job application screening or ...) question? If not, I'd be very interested to know what it's needed for.

Comment: By your description of the problem, wouldn't your result be:  [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[5,5,5,5,5,5,5],[2,2,2,2,2],[9,9,9,9]]?

Comment: "Does not work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. Exactly what result do you expect, and how does that differ from the actual result produced?

Comment: Oops. I've made an answer before I saw those comments. Is it correct to keep it ?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan not homework, it's for work

Comment: @Josh yeah, but i can use the value in indices[0] as the end point of the interval, when done, it's going to be the start point and so on

Comment: This is two questions - how to find the indices and how to build the secondary arrays.  Please update your question to ask one question only per SO reqs.

Comment: @Madbreaks i'm pretty sure it is just one question.

Comment: I think it is one question but the example have to be clearer. When I see the pre and post array e.g. the 4s vanished. Not sure if this meant to be. So please specify as already pointed out in the comment above :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution :

```
//the result array, holding other arrays
var array_map = {};

var arreglo = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,9,9,9.9];

for ( u=0; u <= arreglo.length; u++){

        //grab a number from the input array
        var item = arreglo[u];

        //get an object from array_map
        var indices = array_map[item];

        //if the object does not exist ...
        if (!indices) {
            indices = []; // ... create it ^^ ....
            array_map[item] = indices; //... and store it in the result.
        }

        //push the number into the object
        indices.push(item);
}

console.log(array_map);
```

An error you have : u in your loop makes you iterates on indexes, not values.

Comment: Would do it the same way. Hope it's ok I've wrote some comments for the code. They key is to use the number from the original array `arreglo` (here called `item`) as the key in the result array `array_map[item]`. Then you only have to +1 this item to the array. The result will hold correctly sorted arrays. Also you avoid stuff like `if ( arreglo[u] !=  arreglo[u + 1])` which is plain ugly for the last iteration step (where `arreglo[arreglo.length+1]` is undefined :C

Answer (score 0):

As for the indices:

```
var prev = false,
    indeces = [];

for(var i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
    if(arreglo[i] !== prev){
        prev = arreglo[i];
        indices.push(i);
    }
}
```

...however, this will not create your separate arrays (but I don't see that you're attempting to do so in your code either).

Answer (score 0):

```
indices = []; // fill with information when items in array change
arreglo = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,5,5,5,9,9,9,9];

array[0]=[]

for(var i = 0 ; i < arreglo.length ; i++ ){
 var value = arreglo[i]
 if (typeof(array[value]) == "undefined"){
  array[0].push(array[value])
  array[value]=[array[value]]
 }else{
  array[value].push(array[value])
 }
}
```

this will give you a list of hash locations that have your 'buckets'. array[0] is your list of locations that you can iterate through, and then at each one you have your bucket of values..so

```
array[0][0] == 1
array[1] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
array[0][1] == 2
array[2] = [2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in previous versions missing sort of the array. So my 
version is below.

In addition I wanted to reduce IF conditions as possible.

```
var arreglo = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9.9];
// First of all sort the array
arreglo.sort();
var outPutArray = [];
var arrLength = arreglo.length;
var tmpArray = []

for (var i = 1; i <= arrLength; i++) {
var tmpValue = arreglo[i];
var previousValue  =arreglo[i-1];

tmpArray.push(previousValue)

if (tmpValue != previousValue) {
        outPutArray.push(tmpArray);

        // The values are differents, so empty temp array
        tmpArray = [];
    }
}
```